# checkBox listener in getview

Tags: android, checkbox, listener, android-checkbox

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           View row = convertView;
            if(row==null)
            { // Object reuse
                inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorite_row, parent, false);
            }
            stationName1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textFavoriteItemInRow);
            stationName1.setText(stationNames[position]);
            cb=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.cbCheck);
//              if (!st.getStations()[position].isFavorite())
//              {
//                  cb.setChecked(true);
//                  st.getStations()[position].setFavorite(true);
//              }
//              else
//              {
//                  cb.setChecked(false);
//                  st.getStations()[position].setFavorite(true);
//              }



        return row;
    }
```

well as you can see the "if" question isn't good....
because its "getview" when I show this, the lines that are shown are checked(not all of them which is wierd)
I want to start as default, that they are all unchecked... and only when i press the button it will check them...

(eventually, I would like to save it in "shared prefences" and then upload the information... but lets start with this...

Comment: I have seen this in a site, but I dont know how to use it...

To determine which rows have been selected in Multiple mode you need to loop through the CheckedItemPositions SparseBooleanArray. A sparse array is like a dictionary that only contains entries where the value has been changed, so you must traverse the entire array looking for true values to know what has been selected in the list as illustrated in the following code snippet:

Comment: var sparseArray = FindViewById<ListView>(Android.Resource.Id.List).CheckedItemPositions;
for (var i = 0; i < sparseArray.Size(); i++ )
   Console.Write(sparseArray.KeyAt(i) + "=" + sparseArray.ValueAt(i) + ",");
Console.WriteLine();

Comment: u posted it again ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650172/click-listener-checkbox-on-android/21650345#21650345